# How to do this query using expression in LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, entity

```
select t.*
from Task t
inner join Project p on a.ProjectId = t.ProjectId
where p.ProjectTypeId IN    (   select ptg.ProjectTypeId
                                from UserGroup ug 
                                inner join ProjectTypeGroup ptg on ug.GroupId = ptg.GroupId
                                where ug.UserId = 1 -- MUTABLE VALUE
                            )
```

Comment: What is your attempt?

Comment: I dont know how to use Contains or whatever to do the same thing in LINQ, I tried several ways, with no success

Comment: Ok. Add your entities and also your _several ways_ of doing it.

Comment: _task.Where( t => _projectType. Join(UserGroup, tg => tg.GroupId, ug => ug.GroupId, (tg, ug) => new {tg, ug}). Where(n => n.ug.UserId == loggedUserId).Contains(t => t.ProjectTypeId) – Daniel Lopes 27 mins ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this.

```
from t in Task
join p in Project
    on t.ProjectId equals p.ProjectId
let subQ = ( from ug in UserGroup
             join ptg in ProjectTypeGroup
                on ug.GroupId equals ptg.GroupId
             where ug.UserId == 1
             select ptg.ProjectTypeId)
where subQ.Contains(p.ProjectTypeId)  
select t
```

or you can use this.

```
 int loggedUserId = 1;

 var _userGroups = 
    UserGroup.Join(ProjectTypeGroup, 
            t => t.GroupId, p => p.GroupId, 
            (t, p) => new {t, p}) 
        .Where(n => n.t.UserId == loggedUserId)
        .Select(s => s.p.ProjectTypeId);

 var projectTypeIds = 
    Task.Join(Project, 
            t => t.ProjectId, p => p.ProjectId, 
            (t, p) => new {t, p}) 
        .Where(n => _userGroups.Contains(n.p.ProjectTypeId) )
        .Select(n => n.t); 

 projectTypeIds.ToList();
```

Comment: thank you, I'm using expression because this is the pattern in this project, I need to split in 2 queries using expressions:

var projectTypeIds = _projectType
    .Join(UserGroup, tg => tg.GroupId, ug => ug.GoupId, (tg, ug) => new {tg, ug})
    .Where(n => n.ug.UserId == loggedUserId).Select(n => n.tg.ProjectTypeId);
    
return await _task.
    OrderByDescending(t => t.CreationDate).
             Where(t => projectTypeIds.Contains(t.ProjectTypeId)).

Answer (score 1):

In the attempt query given by you, I don't see Task being used.

Since there is no relation between your sub-query and your main query, you should split them in to two queries:

```
var projTypeIds = (from ug in UserGroup 
                   join ptg in ProjectTypGroup on ug.GroupId equals ptg.GroupId
                   where ug.UserId == 1
                   select ptg.ProjectTypeId).ToList()
```

Once you have your output, check for `.Contains`

```
var task = (from t in Task
            join p in Project on p.ProjectId equals t.ProjectId
            where projTypeIds.Contains(p.ProjectTypeId)
            select t).FirstOrDefault();
```

I assume you need only one object from this query hence used `.FirstOrDefault()`, if you are expecting a list using `.ToList()`

Comment: Sorry, acttualy, I retypethe code, the correct would be _task.Where( t => _projectType. Join(UserGroup, tg => tg.GroupId, ug => ug.GroupId, (tg, ug) => new {tg, ug}). Where(n => n.ug.UserId == loggedUserId).Contains(t => t.ProjectTypeId), I trying get a list of tasks that the user can see with association between UserGroups and ProjectTypes

Comment: Thank you, I got it splitting the query, but I'm affraid about performance of this, I did this, used expression to keep the project pattern:

var projectTypeIds = _projectType
    .Join(UserGroup, tg => tg.GroupId, ug => ug.GoupId, (tg, ug) => new {tg, ug})
    .Where(n => n.ug.UserId == loggedUserId).Select(n => n.tg.ProjectTypeId);
    
return await _task.
    OrderByDescending(t => t.CreationDate).
             Where(t => projectTypeIds.Contains(t.ProjectTypeId)).